# Swift complains "extraneous argument label"

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Trying to start some Swift work. I am using

```
var imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, compressionQuality:1.0)
```

but I get a warning "extraneous argument label 'compressionQuality' in call. I thought that in Swift the secondary parameters were either required or 'allowed' to be labelled, but this won't let me use it at all- fails building if I leave it. Since this is a system function, I can't use the # to require it. But I WOULD like to be able to name as many parameters as possible to make code more readable for myself, I like the ObjC method names, as verbose as they sometimes are.

Is there a way to set a compiler flag to allow extra argument labels?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't do like that, because that function doesn't declare any external parameter name. Internal parameter names can only be used within the function that declares them.

In Swift [UIImageJPEGRepresentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/1624115-uiimagejpegrepresentation?language=objc) method is declared as:

```
func UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_ image: UIImage!,
                             _ compressionQuality: CGFloat) -> NSData!
```

Check both parameters, both have internal name only so you can't use:

```
var imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, compressionQuality:1.0)
```

Change that to:

```
var imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,1.0)
```

---

### Update Swift 4.2:

In swift 4.2, the above mentioned methods are no longer available. Instead of that you need to use:

```
// For JPEG
let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)

// For PNG
let imageData = image.pngData()
```

Refer the API Document for more: [Images & PDF](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/images_and_pdf)

Comment: OK I was unaware of internal-only parameter names. Autocomplete showed it initially to me.

Comment: I am getting that error, but only for the first of two parameters: the second one causes no error. That is, I have `func dummy(a:Int, b:Int)` and if I call it like `dummy(a:1, b: 2)`, I get the error on `a:`(unless I prepend a `#`, of course). But if I call it like this: `dummy(1, b: 2);`, the euro goes away. Any idea?

Comment: @NicolasMiari: Except init methods all other functions the first parameter label is not mandatory, else you mark it as mandatory. So in your case the first parameter label "a" is not required when calling that function.

Comment: Link is dead. Go to this, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/1624115-uiimagejpegrepresentation?language=objc

Comment: @user3207158: Thanks for pointing out about the dead-link, I've updated the answer with new link and also added code for Swift 4.2.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, but Xcode was complaining about it in one of my funcions.

Turned out to be an extra `}` in my code, making the subsequent function declarations to be outside my class.

The error message was weird as hell, so I hope it hepls somebody else.